# AMR Encoder for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-audio, amr

I was trying to find an `AMR Encoder` for iPhone,that I can integrate with my Voice recording application.

Comment: If your problem is solved,please explain here. If you have done some workaround you can mention that.

Answer (score 3):

This is addressed in this topic, basically you can't out of the box but there is open source you could try to incorporate.

[How can I record AMR audio format on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276644/how-can-i-record-amr-audio-format-on-the-iphone/614686)

There is an open source AMR encoder linked below, but it does not seem to be ported to the iPhone yet.

http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/amr

Comment: Hi john,If you have any suggestion please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need, [opencore-amr](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/)

It is extracted from Android source, and it's cool, portable to iPhone