# recorder works on iPhone 3GS but not on iPhone 3G

Tags: iphone, avaudiorecorder, 3g, iphone-3gs

I have a AVAudioRecorder, which gets initialized like:

```
_recorder = [AVAudioRecorder alloc];
NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:2] autorelease];
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityLow] forKey: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey]; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self getActualSoundPath]];
[_recorder initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings  error:nil];    
[_recorder setDelegate:self];
```

This code works perfectly in my Simulator and on my iPhone 3GS but not on the older iPhone 3G...

What is the problem on that?

Thanks
Markus

Answer (score 6):

The iPhone 3G doesnt have support for hardware AAC encoding like the 3GS/4/4S. You could use linear PCM, but thats not compressed.

See this thread for supported formats: [How can I record AMR audio format on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276644/how-can-i-record-amr-audio-format-on-the-iphone)

Apple lossless (kAudioFormatAppleLossless) and iLBC (kAudioFormatiLBC) seems to work fine on the iPhone 3G.

kAudioFormatAppleIMA4 is recommended to use, but its not recognized by mobile Safari.

/Marcus